# EasyGIS.NET - Shapefiles from a Coordinate Reference System are invisible

Tags: c#, gis, easygis.net

I'm trying to get familiar with the EasyGIS.NET Library

[EasyGIS.NET - GitHub](https://github.com/wfletcher/EasyGIS.NET)

[Easygisdotnet - Website/](https://www.easygisdotnet.com/)

(if anyone can create a Tag that would be useful)

So far, a great library and fun to go through the examples.

The issue:
I have the CRS set up on the map as follows:

```
sfMap1.MapCoordinateReferenceSystem = EGIS.Projections.CoordinateReferenceSystemFactory.Default.GetCRSById(EGIS.Projections.CoordinateReferenceSystemFactory.Wgs84EpsgCode);
sfMap1.UseMercatorProjection = true;
```

and I add a Shapefile like this:

```
ShapeFile shapeFile = new ShapeFile(path);
this.sfMap1.AddShapeFile(shapeFile);
shapeFile.RenderSettings.SelectFillColor = Color.Green;
shapeFile.RenderSettings.SelectOutlineColor = Color.Blue;
shapeFile.RenderSettings.IsSelectable = true;
shapeFile.SelectRecord(0, true);
```

What I'm finding is that when I bring in a Shapefile that is projcted using WGS84 everything works fine.
The green and white shapes below are such an example.
However, if I bring in a Shapefile that is projected to BritishNationalGrid it appears to load the shapefile but it's invisible.

Not how when I hover over an empty area, it can see "Record : 59" which is from the BritishNationalGrid shapefile I loaded. I've not worked out if it's in the right place or not. Hard to tell when it's invisible.

[image: CRS Issue]

If I set:

```
sfMap1.UseMercatorProjection = false;
```

Then the BritishNationalGrid loads just fine, looks like this, it's just in the wrong place which is to be expected.

[image]

I get the exact same results if I use the EasyGis Examples on their website.

So my two questions are:

1. Why are the BritishNationalGrid shapefile invisible, but clearly loaded?
2. Will the BritishNationalGrid shapefile be automatically converted to WGS84 or do I need to carry out an extra step. If so, what's the method to achieve this.

Many thanks

Comment: Can someone set up a Tag for easygis.net as you need 1500 score to do so.